# Can't compile lambda when I want to catch something outside

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, lambda

When I want to catch something outside the lambda, the compiling errors occurs. here is the code:

```
int caller(int (*callback)(void *arg), void * arg = NULL) {
  return callback(arg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  const char *str = "world";
  caller([&](void *arg) {
      printf("hello %s\n", str);
      return 0;
  }, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

But it's ok if I change the `printf` inside lambda like this (not using the outside variables):

```
printf("hello %s\n", str)
```

I tried to compile the source with apple g++ 4.2 and gnu g++ 4.6

Comment: Please give us the error message from your compiler.

Comment: Also, your changed `printf` is actually unchanged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lambdas can only be converted to function pointers when they are stateles, ie have no captures defined.

Have a look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and read about `ClosureType::operator ret(*)(params)()`

EDIT:

If it is up to you to define the callback parameter, define it using `std::function`, which can take any type of callable object, including lambdas. See below, it should [compile fine](http://ideone.com/iNQhxe) with it (`#include <functional>` though).

```
int caller(std::function<int(void*)> callback, void * arg = NULL) {
  return callback(arg);
}
```

If you can't change the callback, then you should just pass `str` as the second parameter to the callback and print it out in lambda, as in here:

```
caller([](void *arg) {
      printf("hello %s\n", (const char*)arg);
      return 0;
  }, str);
```

(I know this actually won't compile due to const non const conversion, but you get what I mean).

Comment: Actually I'm using the second way you described. 
Sometimes I want to use lambda in some system api such as pthread_create and I have a lot of variables which I want to pass to the callback. 
It's very annoying if I pass all the variables via a pair or tuple or something else and then convert void * to the proper type. Is there any good way to handle this situation?

Comment: Well, you can always wrap references to those variables in some structure and pass the pointer to that structure as a callback parameter, if possible. I know it's a lot more hassle than captures, but sometimes it's the only way.

Comment: It's counterproductive to take a `std::function<int(void*)>` and a `void*`, and then pass the `void*` as the argument. You needlessly restrict the arguments you can use. Just use a single `std::function<int()>`, the few people who have a `int(void*)` can still use `std::bind`.